# Feeder service is costing me money

Tags: openttd

So I have a feeder service. A train drops off goods (i.e. is ordered to transfer) and a truck picks these up and makes the short journey into town.

The problem I seem to be having however is that whenever my truck makes the delivery it actually loses money. I'm assuming this is because the train station is slightly further away and the train gets overpaid for the transfer. Is there a way I can fix this? Short of demolishing and moving my train station?

Comment: Money shouldn't be gained until goods reach their destination.  A transfer stop shouldn't be paying you.

Comment: If you set up a train to transfer to an intermediate station it will be listed as making a profit (provided the route is profitable). In either case it's the truck that is actually delivering the goods that is losing money each time it delivers to the destination.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out there is a page on the [wiki](http://wiki.openttd.org/Negative_income_with_feeder_service) about this.
Essentially when the cargo is transferred the game estimates how much it thinks the payment will be. This could be less (and in my case it was) than the actual amount.

In general this can be reduced by keeping the speed similar and taking the most direct route.

In my case (where this is unavoidable) there is an advanced setting "Percentage of leg profit to pay in feeder systems" which allows you to reduce the payment the initial transfer makes. This leaves more money for the final leg and sorted my problem.